# Angularjs: Expand only one table row at time from the table created using ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, mysql, angularjs

I am creating a table using ng-repeat which has expandable rows. I should be able to expand one table row at a time. if I expand a row then the previously expanded row should close.
Please let me know if any further details are required. Thank you.

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/yYq1dt?p=preview)

```
<tbody>
  <tr ng-repeat-start="person in people">
    <td>
      <button ng-if="person.expanded" ng-click="person.expanded = false">-</button>
      <button ng-if="!person.expanded" ng-click="person.expanded = true">+</button>
    </td>
    <td>{{person.name}}</td>
    <td>{{person.gender}}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr ng-if="person.expanded" ng-repeat-end="">
    <td colspan="3">{{person.details}}</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: please my sample code here http://plnkr.co/edit/yYq1dt?p=preview

Comment: Please edit your question and add your plnkr there.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can write a function to achieve this. The function will take the current row as a parameter and hide all other rows and enable only the current row.

**HTML**:

```
 <button ng-if="!person.expanded" ng-click="expandSelected(person)">+</button>
```

**JS**

```
  $scope.expandSelected=function(person){
    $scope.people.forEach(function(val){
      val.expanded=false;
    })
    person.expanded=true;

  }
```

**Working Plunker**: http://plnkr.co/edit/jpMCxzAwdbZYUlRylJPN?p=preview

Comment: use `.forEach` for this purpose? `.map` is for converting an array to another array.

Comment: I have updated the answer. map will return an array back with same values. So when should one use .map?

Comment: Let's say in a delete API that accepts array of user id's, you can transform your user array `[{id: 1, name: 'a'}, ...]` into `[1]` using `.map`

Answer (score 1):

As per your requirement, no need to go through whole array to check if any other row is opened and close that.
just store the rownumber as detail and use that in your tr like this

```
<tr ng-repeat-start="person in people track by $index">
            <td>
              <button ng-if="rowNumber == $index" ng-click="detailView(-1)">-</button>
              <button ng-if="rowNumber != $index" ng-click="detailView($index)">+</button>
            </td>
            <td>{{person.name}}</td>
            <td>{{person.gender}}</td>
          </tr>
          <tr ng-if="rowNumber == $index" ng-repeat-end="">
            <td colspan="3">{{person.details}}</td>
          </tr>
```

And a function to help this

```
$scope.detailView = function(index){
    $scope.rowNumber = index
  }
```

Comment: You can also use the object itself as the indicator
`<button ng-if="selected == person" ng-click="selected = person">+</button>`